Remote journal over AutoSSH tunnel
I'm having several remote sites (test setups), each having multiple Linux devices, uploading their journal remotely to Raspberry Pis in that remote site. I'm trying to forward these journals via AutoSSH to my office, where I have a central journal server. The connection from remote sites to office is over cellular data and it is unreliable, there are lots of reconnects.
Easiest solution is to just establish port forward from Raspberry's journal port 19532 to office's journal collector. This works fine, except when AutoSSH pipes are being disconnected. This causes that each device looses their journal upload connection and their systemd-journal-remote services need to be restart. This happens automatically, no problem. But this causes several seconds of journal data being lost.
Is there any remote journal proxy system, which could receive journal events and reliably forward those to another host over AutoSSH tunnel?
I'm using Zabbix to monitor those remote sites and devices there. Zabbix has very clever zabbix-proxy, which runs on remote site Raspberrys and it tackles AutoSSH reconnects very well, no data is lost. Similar functionality for journal logs would be ideal.

Thanks. This looks like a good idea, it would anyway require some scripting in journal-remote-upload service file's PreStart place.
Can you give a bit more information how this HTTP header could be added in reconnection request? The journal-remote-uploader service now just restarts automatically.

Thank you, this was the answer to my question. :)

The answer depends on whether your "office" is in "active" mode and
"pulling" data from the remote, or if the remote is "pushing" data
to the "passive" mode office service.
In the first case, you might be able to something using the Range: <cursor> http header in the reconnection request
systemd-journal-remote --getter='curl "-HRange: ..." http://...'

Get the last cursor with journalctl --show-cursor --lines=1  on the file received so far.
In the second case you should simply be able to add option --save-state
to the journal-remote-upload command to have the last cursor saved. It isn't
clear from the man page if on restart this option will make the program
read the saved cursor and continue from there. If it doesn't then you can
use --after-cursor=.... using the value written into the default file
/var/lib/systemd/journal-upload/state.
